# read text file using bash shell script that change some times a day

Tags: bash, file, variables, awk, sed

I get this kind of file and I would like to read each line and put it in a var. If possible using a shell script. The content changes each time I load it (several times a day), 13 lines in the file:

```
TestTourcompagny 
Simulation organization (will be fixed later!)
Blake, Stef (USA) 
Trump, Donald (USA) 
90 
10 
5 
1 
4 
4 
2 
2 
0:12
```

I would like to echoe each line with `echo $var` and write each one in a new file.

Thanks for your help

Comment: What have you tried so far? How should the output files be named?

Comment: `while read -r line; do echo ${line}; done < file_with_13_lines`; if that doesn't work then please update your question with more details, and as Freddy has mentioned, what you've tried so far and the expected output

Comment: When you say `write each one in a new file` - do you mean each line or the whole block of text on each iteration or something else? Is it appending to those same files on each iteration or overwriting them or creating brand new files? Please [edit] your question to show the expected output (in separate files) given your posted sample input.

Answer (score 0):

Read it line by line using a while read loop.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

n=1
while read -r var; do
  printf '%d. %s\n' "$n" "$var" | tee -a "line_${n}_from_file.txt"
  ((n++))
done < file.txt
```

check the files.

```
ls
file.txt  line_11_from_file.txt  line_13_from_file.txt  line_2_from_file.txt  
line_4_from_file.txt  line_6_from_file.txt  line_8_from_file.txt     line_10_from_file.txt  line_12_from_file.txt  line_1_from_file.txt    line_3_from_file.txt  line_5_from_file.txt  line_7_from_file.txt   line_9_from_file.txt
```

- It creates a new file with the line number from file.txt by incrementing the value of `$n` starting from `1`
- The `-a` from tee appends the output to the file, if that is not the intention just remove it.

Comment: See [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice).

Comment: hi, thanks for your help. What i want is putting each line in a var wich i can echoes to a file: while read  a b c d e f g h i j k l m ; do echo $a >TEXTFILE; echo $b >>TEXTFILE etc ..... ; done

Comment: @EricFeillant, that idea is flawed, what if you ran out of letters in the alphabet?